# how to share a session object created in fixture having scope as session in pytest / unittest tests

Tags: installation, pytest, fixtures

we are creating tests by implementing unittest and pytest in python. we want to use fixtures for doing setup and tear down at session and test level. 
How to use object created in setup session fixture to be used in setup of function fixture. Example I want to create a driver object like driver = webdriver.Chrome() of intializing the browser and using the driver object in test methods and function scope fixture.

conftest.py
    import pytest

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setupsession():
    print("Starting Session")

    yield
    print("Ending Session")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def setupmodule(request):
    print("starting module")
    yield
    print("Ending Module")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setupclass(request):
    print("starting module")
    yield
    print("Ending Module")
```

Basetest.py
    import unittest

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print("inside Base setup")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("inside base teardown")
```

test.py
    import pytest
    from wav2.fixtures.base_test import BaseTest

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setupsession", "setupmodule")
class TestSample(BaseTest):
    def test1(self):
        print("calling inside test test1")
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test2(self):
        print("calling inside test tes`enter code here`t2")
```

Answer (score 4):

A fixture can use other fixture too.  That means you can use a session fixture inside a module fixture, you can use a module fixture inside a class fixture and so on. You can also use same scope fixture in other fixture. Only 2 limit is that you can not import a fixture backwards (like using a function level fixture in the class level fixture) and there can not be a circular dependency.

Please find the same example given in question with an additional fixture with `scope=function` and using a fixture inside another fixture.

conftest.py

```py
import pytest
import unittest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setupsession(request):
    print("Starting Session")

    yield "session_obj"
    print("Ending Session")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def setupmodule(request, setupsession):
    print("starting module")
    yield setupsession, "module_obj"
    print("Ending Module")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setupclass(request, setupmodule):
    print("starting class")
    yield (*setupmodule, "class_obj")
    print("Ending class")


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def setupmethod(request, setupclass):
    print("starting method")
    yield (*setupclass, "class_obj")
    print("Ending method")
```

Note: As we have created setupmethod fixture, it is not necessary to create BaseTest with `setUp` and `tearDown` method. But, it's your choice depending on the structure of hte test cases.

test_file.py

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setupmethod")
class TestSample(BaseTest):
    def test1(self):
        print("calling inside test test1")
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test2(self):
        print("calling inside test tes`enter code here`t2")
```

Reference: http://devork.be/talks/advanced-fixtures/advfix.html

Comment: if i have created a object / variable in session fixture and if i change the value of it in tests or function fixtures, will the value of object / variable persist in session fixture yield statement

Comment: Yes. But it depends on what type of value the session fixture is yielding. If it's a string or number (immutable objects), it will yield the same value. However, if it is a list or dictionary (something that will be passed by reference), that would create an issue as the value will be changed. You can refer to https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php

Comment: i create a driver =webdriver.Chrome() selenium object in session and add this driver object to all instances of the classes. `session = request.node  for item in session.items cls = item.getparent(pytest.Class) setattr(cls.obj, "driver",driver)` when i change the instance of the driver in one test , same is not being reflected in other tests.

Comment: That should work. Just make sure that there are not dependencies between any two test cases.  each test case opens the required webpage again in the start of the test case and does the whole process.

Comment: sure thanks! instead can i use pytest.driver = webdriver.Chrome() so i can use this object anywhere in the tests and also in yield part of session fixtures

Comment: Sure thing. You can set & get the driver as a property of `pytest.config`.